# Java Is it possible to get the Variable name of a jButton?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button, jbutton

I can't come up with any other way of doing this. I'm trying to get the variable name of a java button which I've already declared so I can loop through a Database (Which has a screen field to access the correct product) and set the desired text to that jButton. I can do this by manually setting each jButtons text or setting a hard codded text through the Netbeans GUI. But I was looking to see if there's a more efficient way of doing this.

## Code that can achieve this

```
    ArrayList<Products> myList = myProductsDataHandler.getAllProducts();
    myList.forEach((var i) ->
    {
        if (i.getScreen() == 0)
        {
            btnProduct1.setText(i.getProductName());
        }
        else if (i.getScreen() == 1)
        {
            btnProduct2.setText(i.getProductName());
        }
        else if (i.getScreen() == 2)
        {
            btnProduct3.setText(i.getProductName());
        }
        else if (i.getScreen() == 3)
        {
            btnProduct4.setText(i.getProductName());
        }
        else if (i.getScreen() == 4)
        {
            btnProduct5.setText(i.getProductName());
        }
        else if (i.getScreen() == 5)
        {
            btnProduct6.setText(i.getProductName());
        }
        else if (i.getScreen() == 6)
        {
            btnProduct7.setText(i.getProductName());
        }
        else if (i.getScreen() == 7)
        {
            btnProduct8.setText(i.getProductName());
        }
        else if (i.getScreen() == 8)
        {
            btnProduct9.setText(i.getProductName());
        }
```

## Code I need help with

```
        int btnInt = 1;
        String btnStr = "btnProduct";
        btnCatagory1.setText(i.getCategory());
        Component[] components = pnlOrder.getComponents();
        for(Component component : components)
        {
            if(component instanceof JButton)
            {
                System.out.println(btnStr+btnInt);
                JButton button = (JButton) component;
                System.out.println(button.getName());
                if (button.getName().contains(btnStr+btnInt))
                {
                    btnProduct1.setText(i.getProductName());
                    btnInt++;
                }
            }
            }
        });
```

It's an Epos system and when the program is executed I want to get texts from the Database and set it to desired buttons. There are only 9 buttons. I have tried getName() but it returns null. Is there any other I can achieve this. Thanks

Comment: variable names are erased when compiling (unless the debug flag is on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your buttons you can also add each button to an `ArrayList`:

```
List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
buttons.add(btnProduct1);
buttons.add(btnProduct2);
```

Then when you want to update the text on the button you simply use:

```
JButton button = buttons.get( i.getScreen() );
button.setText( i.getProductName() );
```

Answer (score 1):

You used setText() therefore should be using getText().

Had you used setName() you would use getName().

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#getText()